# QT request "QObject::connect: No such slot BackEnd::RequestReceived"

Tags: c++, qt

Im trying to make a request to get some data with QT.

my backend.h

```
#ifndef BACKEND_H
#define BACKEND_H

#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QObject>
#include <QString>
#include <QNetworkReply>
class BackEnd : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString userName READ userName WRITE setUserName NOTIFY userNameChanged)

public:
    explicit BackEnd(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    QString userName();
    void setUserName(const QString &userName);

signals:
    void userNameChanged();

private:
    QString m_userName;
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager;
    //also tried: void RequestReceived(QNetworkReply* reply); << without space after QNetworkReply
    void RequestReceived(QNetworkReply * reply);
};
#endif // BACKEND_H
```

my .cpp

```
#include "backend.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <QtNetwork>

BackEnd::BackEnd(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);


}
void BackEnd::RequestReceived(QNetworkReply * reply){
    QByteArray rawData = reply->readAll();
    QString textData(rawData);
    qDebug() << textData;
}

QString BackEnd::userName()
{
    return m_userName;
}

void BackEnd::setUserName(const QString &userName)
{
    if (userName == m_userName)
        return;

    m_userName = userName;
    connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
            this, SLOT(RequestReceived(QNetworkReply*)));
    manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("https://google.com")));
    emit userNameChanged();

}
```

I found similair questions but almost all answers say Q_OBJECT should be added (which I have). Im very new to qt but if I understand correctly the error indicates that I do not have a

> BackEnd::RequestReceived(QNetworkReply*)

method, which I do have. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mark `void RequestReceived(QNetworkReply * reply);` as a slot:

`Q_SLOT void RequestReceived(QNetworkReply * reply);`